# Как склеить видео ffmpeg( все в папке)

Tags: ffmpeg

Как можно, используя утилиту [ffmpeg](https://ffmpeg.org/), одной командой склеить все видео которые находятся в одной папке?

Comment: Подправил вопрос, чтобы было понятнее. Для закрывающих: на мой взляд, это вполне нормальный вопрос про shell, ответ на него существует в документации и скоро появится здесь.

Comment: В вопросе не помешает указание ОС.

Comment: Позвольте нам [продолжить обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/29102/discussion-between-nick-volynkin-and--).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Выполнение этой операции хорошо описано в документации ffmpeg'a:

```
ffmpeg -f concat -i <(for f in ./*.wav; do echo "file '$PWD/$f'"; done) -c copy output.wav
ffmpeg -f concat -i <(printf "file '$PWD/%s'\n" ./*.wav) -c copy output.wav
ffmpeg -f concat -i <(find . -name '*.wav' -printf "file '$PWD/%p'\n") -c copy output.wav
```

Подробнее можно узнать тут:

https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Concatenate

Comment: Bezarius, знал бы я хорошо английский)